# Understanding the behaviour of .loc in item(list) assignment

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01 23:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01 23:00:00'), 0),
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), 0),
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), 0)],
           names=['dt_calc', 'dt_fore', 'positional_index']), columns=['temp', 'temp_2'])
idx = df.index[0]
```

Now I want to replace the cells with a list object(I know that storing complex objects in pandas columns is generally not a good practice) so I do:

```
df.loc[idx, 'temp'] = pd.Series([[1, 2, 3]], index=[idx])
#It is working fine and as expected
#This is for example..it has nothing to do with my actual question
```

but if I try to assign a list or nested list like this It will throw me an error(as expected):

```
df.loc[idx,'temp']=[1,2,3]
df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[1,2,3]]
df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[[1,2,3]]]
```

But Now If I try to assign a list of 3 or more dimensions with string in it:

```
df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[['1','2','3']]]
#It is working
#But If now if I assign a list of 3 or more dimensions with int in it after running the above code:
df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[[1,2,3]]]
#It is also working
```

So depending on the above observations(I am using python 3.9 and pandas version is '1.3.0')

**My question:**

what is this behaviour of `loc` accessor?

Comment: I would only assume, it throws an error with the `df.loc[idx,"temp"] = [1,2,3]` are you sure it fails with `df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[1,2,3]]`?

Comment: @CutePoison yes sir I am sure

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer this question partially. I can't provide technical details. But hopefully it helps to give some idea what is happening.

Pandas optimizes A LOT under the hood.

In the case

```
df.loc[idx,'temp']=[1,2,3]
```

pandas automatically detects you want to set an numpy-array-like-structure on a column with type int64. It switches to a fast track optimized for arrays. Then it detects you provided too many elements and throws an error.

In the case of

```py
df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[['1','2','3']]]
```

pandas doesn't use the fast track, because it's clearly not a numpy-array-like structure. It also changes the dtype to object. After the dtype is changed to object the `.loc` accessor doesn't try to use the fast track anymore. That's why the operation `df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[['1','2','3']]]` is working.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your time and answer....like  you said 'After the dtype is changed to object the .loc accessor doesn't try to use the fast track anymore' actually the dtype of element inside list are of dtype string but the wrapper remains list

Comment: And also Sir if I assign like `np.array([[['1','2','3']]])` why it works because it's a numpy array so why fast track allow that?

Comment: Fair points. The check what's a numpy-like-array seems to be quite complex. I can't provide details, because I didn't find the relevant check in the source code.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your time since it's not a proper answer so I can't upvote you here but as an appreciation of your help +2...btw If needed I will bounty this question...thanks for the help sir **:)*

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer to this question but it's working only because the two first levels of your MultiIndex are dates:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([[2, 3]],
      index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('foo', 'bar', 'baz')], names=['A', 'B', 'C']),
      columns=['V1', 'V2'])
idx1 = df1.index[0]
```

```
>>> idx1
('foo', 'bar', 'baz')

>>> df1.loc[idx1,'temp'] = [[[1,2,3]]]
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If you append one level to your dataframe, the same logic doesn't work:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01 23:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01 23:00:00'), 0, 1),
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 00:00:00'), 0, 2),
            (pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 01:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-02 01:00:00'), 0, 3)],
           names=['dt_calc', 'dt_fore', 'positional_index', 'additional_index']), columns=['temp', 'temp_2'])

idx = df.index[0]
```

```
>>> idx
(Timestamp('2019-07-01 23:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-07-01 23:00:00'), 0, 1)

>>> df.loc[idx,'temp']=[1,2,3]
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

>>> df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[1,2,3]]
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

>>> df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[[1,2,3]]]
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

>>> df.loc[idx,'temp']=[[[[1,2,3]]]]
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The answer is probably [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/313665ab41ebef44e093730ac05927cd632395ae/pandas/core/indexing.py#L453). You can open an issue to github.

Comment: Thanks corralien but that's not the case...as you said 'only because the two first levels of your MultiIndex are dates'....assignment of list is not working even if the first 2 levels are dates